# How to refactor this Java code so it creates a String List of key:value pairs as opposed to printing them out?

Tags: java, performance, dictionary, hashmap, comparator

So I saw some code online that I implemented into my program to sort a hashmap<String, int> based on the values of the integers, and it works successfully but only outputs the values, I need to store the values into a String list but don't understand the code well enough to do this and have been failing repeatedly, it is confusing me to have so many brackets.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that'd be helpful, I don't even know what to google to find out how to do this, thanks.

```
public List<String> getMaxList(int n, HashMap<String, Integer> itemCount){
        List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> maxList = new ArrayList<>();
        Object[] a = itemCount.entrySet().toArray();
        int n_iterator = n-1;

        Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator() {
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                return ((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) o2).getValue()
                     .compareTo(((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) o1).getValue());
            }
        });

        for (Object e : a) {
            System.out.println(((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) e).getKey() + " : "
                    + ((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) e).getValue());
            if (n_iterator <= 0){
                break;
            } else {
                n_iterator--;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> How to refactor this Java code so it creates a **String List of key:value pairs** as opposed to printing them out?
> Try it like this.

Create some data

```
Map<String, Integer> map =
        Map.of("A", 10, "B", 3, "C", 8, "D", 2);
```

Now stream the map's entry set.  Sort based on the value and convert the entry to a `String:int` string and put in a list.

```
List<String> list = map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Entry.comparingByValue()))
        .map(e -> e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(list);
```

Prints

```
[D:2, B:3, C:8, A:10]
```

To sort in descending order, change the above `sort` method to

```
.sorted(Entry.<String,Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
```

Note that the `Entry` comparator had to be `witnessed` with the types as the compiler could not discern them to properly apply the `reversed()` method. The above simply reverses the natural sorting order for `Integers` which is ascending.

Finally, not all objects provide methods that return comparators, so the following would also have worked.

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue,
                      Comparator.reverseOrder()))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, is there any way I could sort the list in descending order for ease of use? Thanks again.